# jQuery Show Div to clear <li>

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to make it so that when you click on an image on this [**page**](http://bvh.delineamultimedia.com/?page_id=2),  the drop down will clear the 2nd row of images.

I have a

```
clear:both;
```

&

```
float:left
```

on `.superbox-show`

but its still not clearing the 2nd row and pushing the images below when it shows onclick. Ideally I'd like all of the `.superbox-show` divs to show up in the same spot under the row pushing down all of the images if that makes sense.

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle along with posting your code inside question is much more appreciated.

Comment: It's going to be very tricky as long as you're using translate3d to position your images. Try floating them instead.

Comment: @metadept you are correct Isotope is using translate3d to position those elements making it very tuff for superbox to work correctly. :-/

Comment: I think .isotope( 'reLayout' ); is what I want but it does some funky stuff. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You are positioning your images by absolute position using the transform css property.

This means that the images are positioned independently of any floats and a float clear will have no impact on their positioning.

To solve this, use `align: left` to position your images. Then when you insert an item between your images with `clear:both` it will cause your images to resume from a new line.

**Not recommended:** Alternatively, when you show the dialog you need to change the transform css property for all the images after your `.superbox-show`.

Comment: I do have a clear: both; on .superbox-show. It is going to be tricky cause Isotope is using translate3d to postion the divs...